# Who runs the Notary in Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

In case of a consortium of banks in a Corda network consisting of one notary, could you please tell me who will be responsible for running the notary? It is clear that a notary is a network service, so can any bank run the notary as and when it wishes to, to check for double spends or is there one "main" bank/node that takes charge to trigger the notary service. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely up to the network operator. The network can have anything from a single one-node validating notary to hundreds of pooled non-validating notaries.

You mention bank nodes joining and leaving the notary service at will. This is a property of Proof of Work consensus algorithms (miners can come and go as they please without undermining the consensus result), but it's not a property of consensus algorithms in general. If you wanted to adopt this mode, you'd have to use a suitable consensus algorithm for your notary pool. In general, therefore, you'd generally have nodes contributing to the notary pool full-time.

Depending on your use-case, it may also be preferable for paid third-parties to provide the notary pool, rather than having the banks that are transacting also provide the notarisation service.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have a follow up question to this. In the case where a single node in a consortium or a consortium as a whole runs the notary service, how can trust be established between the nodes in a consortium? How can one node trust the other node to run the notary? In the other case where the notary is a 3rd Party, how does all the nodes in the consortium come to an agreement to choose this 3rd party to run the nodes.

Comment: Hey, can you spin this out as a separate question please? :)

Comment: Hi Joel, please find the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793939/trust-and-agreement-between-corda-nodes Thank you :)