# Trust and agreement between Corda nodes

Tags: corda

When a single node in a consortium or a consortium as a whole runs the notary service, how can trust be established between the nodes in a consortium? 
How can one node trust the other node to run the notary? 
In the case, where the notary is a 3rd Party, how does all the nodes in the consortium come to an agreement to choose this 3rd party to run the nodes?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will often be the case that there is no clear node or pool of nodes that can be absolutely trusted to run a notary pool.

In that case, the notary pools should be set up as follows:

- They should run a byzantine-fault tolerant algorithm. This prevents nodes in the pool from maliciously giving bad consensus results
- They should operate in non-validating mode. This prevents nodes in the pool from seeing the contents of the transactions they are deconflicting

With this set up, there is no need to trust the nodes in the notary pool.

Choosing the nodes for these pools would be a network governance matter. In all likelihood, a pool of standard technology service providers will be paid to run a BFT, non-validating pool.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks Joel.